# Taking key data from objects in Array and turning them into a , separated string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, lodash

What method, or [lodash](https://lodash.com/) function would you use to pull out the ids below and generate a comma separated string out of them?

```
var myArray = [
    {
        tag: 'wunwun',
        id: 132
    },
    {
        tag: 'davos',
        id: 452
    },
    {
        tag: 'jon snow',
        id: 678
    }
]
```

---

Like this: `'132, '452', '678'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use `Array#map` to get array of `id` and apply `Array#join` over it.

```js
var myArray = [{
  tag: 'wunwun',
  id: 132
}, {
  tag: 'davos',
  id: 452
}, {
  tag: 'jon snow',
  id: 678
}];
var op = myArray.map(function(item) {
  return item.id;
});
console.log(op.join(', '))
```

Comment: No need of `join`, just call `toString`.

Answer (score 2):

**No need to use a third-party library** for that:

```
var commaSeparatedIds = myArray.map(function(item) {
    return item.id;
}).join(','); // result: '132,452,678'
```

Or if you just want them as an array, skip the `join`:

```
var commaSeparatedIds = myArray.map(function(item) {
    return item.id;
}); // result: ['132', '452', '678']
```

**References:**

- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is easy:

`_.pluck(myArray, 'id').join(', ')`

`_.map` works the same way, but you can also pass in a function instead of an array

Comment: Also just used this: `var terms = _.map(alertSettings.fav_tags, function (tag) {
            return tag.term_id;
        });`

Comment: You don't need the function, you can also just apply the `key`

Answer (score 0):

`myArray.map(function(element){return element.id;}).join(',');`